# What is the type and address of a static array in C++?

Tags: c++

Using Visual Studio Express 2013. I thought I understood static vs dynamic arrays, but the following has me confused:

```
int* a = new int[3]; \\ dynamic array
int** pa = &a;

int b[3]; \\ static array
int** pb = &b; \\ error: cannot convert from 'int (*)[3]' to 'int **'
```

Ok, so I try `int (*)[3] pb = &b;` but it's not even syntactically correct. The Locals Window says pb is an `int[3]`, but `int[3]* pb = &b;` is also incorrect.

[image]

It also seems strange to me that `b` has the same value as `pa`. If I replace the declaration `int b[3];` with a declaration + initialization `int b[3] = {};` then that oddity disappears, so maybe it's just a VS bug:

[image]

But I still can't get at the address of the static array. If I type `&b` in the Immediate Window then I get exactly the same output as if I just typed `b`, which again seems strange by comparison with '&a' and 'a' which are clearly different things:

[image]

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the declaration of `pb` should look like `int (*pb)[3] = &b;`. You just had the identifier in the wrong place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Kerrek said that dynamic arrays are weird part of C++; I say static arrays are weird, with their semantics unlike anything else in the language.

Given an array:

```
int foo[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Pointer to an array:

```
int (*pfoo)[3] = &foo;
```

Reference to an array (surprisingly powerful with templates):

```
int (&rfoo)[3] = foo;
```

Pointer to the first element:

```
int *pa = &foo[0];
assert(*pa == 1);
int *pb = foo; // auto decay!
assert(pa == pb);
assert(pa == foo); // auto decay strikes again
assert(pa+0 == foo+0); // and again
```

Note that the decay-to pointer and pointer to the actual array have same value, since they point to the same memory location:

```
assert((void*)foo == (void*)&foo);
```

But for any array size greater than 1 this assertion will fail:

```
assert((void*)(foo+1) == (void*)(&foo+1));
```

Because:

```
static_assert(sizeof(*(foo+0)) == sizeof(int), "");
static_assert(sizeof(*(&foo)) == sizeof(int[3]), "");
```

Copy-assignment is not possible:

```
int bar[3] = foo; // compile error!
```

... unless it happens in the compiler-generated code:

```
struct workaround { int foo[3]; };
workaround a = { { 1, 2, 3 } };
workaround b = a;
assert(b.foo[0] == 1); // the array got copied!
```

Can't be a result of a function:

```
int (func1())[3]; // syntatically correct, but prohibited by C++
```

So one must resort to workarounds:

```
std::array<int, 3> func2();
void func3( int (&out_arr)[3] );
```

If that's not weird, then I don't know what is.

(Despite that, stack allocation FTW).

Comment: Thanks I learned some good things from this

Answer (score 7):

A dynamic array is a very weird part of C++. It's a type that is never the type of any expression in the language, and you can never see a dynamic array as a whole. When you say `new T[N]`, all you get is a pointer to the first element of the fictitious array of type `T[N]`. (Note also that this is a truly "dynamic type"!)

By contrast, your `b` is an actual array object, so naturally its address has type "pointer to array". If you wanted a pointer to a pointer its first element, you'd first have to create such a pointer:

```
int b[3];
int * b0 = &b[0];  // or just "int * b0 = b;" :-S
int ** pb = &b0;
```

Tbe variable `b0` here is the analogue of your variable `a` in the dynamic example - a pointer variable containing the address of the first array element.

Comment: So what's the analogue of `&a`? That's what I'm looking for ...

Comment: @GeorgeSkelton: If `b0` is the analogue of `a`, then the analogue of `&a` is `&b0`...